# How to rest input ref in mui textfield?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to clear the input of a text field after certain action but I am getting the following error (The value of the input element, required for a controlled component.)

```js
const emailRef = useRef<TextFieldProps>(null);
   
   // Clear logic 
   emailRef.current?.value = null;
   
   
   <TextField
              className={classes.root}
              margin='normal'
              variant='outlined'
              required
              fullWidth
              id='email'
              label='Email Address'
              name='email'
              autoComplete='email'
              autoFocus
              inputRef={emailRef}
              inputProps={{
                style: {
                  transitionDelay: '9999s',
                },
              }}
            />
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `emailRef.current?.value = null;` use this-

```js
emailRef.current?.value = '';
```